# How to have 2 domains allowed to the same Facebook App

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook application to allow visitors to my site to log in using Facebook account.

The problem is that I have 2 domains pointing to the same Website, so when I tried to add the second domain, this error occured:

This must be derived from Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Site URL, Mobile Site URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Check and correct the following domains: hum.cl

How can I do it then?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: You can't. You need to put login on just one domain

Comment: Thanks... so, the only solution i see is that when a user uses the other domain, automatically to redirect him to the domain which was registered in FB.

Comment: Bad luck. customer prefer to use the second domain instead of the already registered in Facebook. Can I safely change domain without affecting registered users?